# Rehydrate store references in Mobx

Tags: mobx

What is the best way to rehydrate your store during app initialization, specifically the references between stores?

For instance, lets say I have 2 api calls:

`/todos -> return array of todos
[{id: 1, person_id: 2}]`

`/persons -> return array of Persons
[{id: 2, name: 'John'}, {id: 3, name: 'Sam'}]`

and a Todo object looks like this

`class Todo {
...
@observable person;
...
}`

Some of the Todos will have a reference to a Person, but not all of them, and not all of the Persons will be referenced, so its not as simple as just scrapping the Persons api call and just returning the Person reference with the Todos api call.

However, we can't be sure that the Persons api call will be returned first, so we cannot just assume to link up the Todo / Person reference whenever the todos response arrives (would like to run calls in parallel)...

Is it just a matter of extra logic in the client side code to ensure we set up all references whenever the data comes in? Or is there some better practice anyone has found in there experience.

#### EDIT

The more I think about it, I'm thinking the most predictable logic would be to always either get or create a reference object.

So in the above example, if the Todos response comes in first, we would look for the Person object with the id of 2, if it exists great, if it doesn't, create it and reference that object.  Then when the persons response comes in it would do the same thing...look for Person with the id of 2, if it exists, update it with the new data, if not, create it.

Anyone have any better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is indeed to load your objects in order, and find them. After that to load them in parallel, and find-or-create placeholders if you refer to them. It's quite a common pattern.